# How to update keyboard firmware?

Tags: usb, keyboard, wine, firmware, peripherals

I recently bought a Durgod Hades 68 mechanical keyboard. It works great out of the box but I'm having some difficulty with the Hera Compiler, the proprietary software that's used to customize the key bindings and RGB effects.  I've tried running Hera using both Wine and a Windows 10 VirtualBox with Extension Pack.  In both cases, the software runs flawlessly but doesn't detect that the keyboard is connected when it's time to actually push the new firmware to the board.

When I run `lsusb`, I see the device.

```
...
Bus 001 Device 125: ID 2f68:4001 Hoksi Technology DGK68C
...
```

Has anyone dealt with anything like this before?

Comment: The Linux kernel **IS** the hardware compatibility layer. If your software is not compatible with Linux, then it won't work. Wine and Virtualbox are both software-only: Neither will affect hardware or firmware. Consider asking the manufacturer for a Linux port of their software. After all, you are their customer.

Comment: Yeah I did contact Durgod and they don't have any plans to support Linux in the near future.  I was hoping someone would come back with "Oh yeah! I know how to fix this. Use these commands and you're good to go." But this might not be one of those situations.